# Remove row on dataframe based on content of series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am geocoding some points to get the nearest place, the geocode process returns an object with a location data inside a dictionary, in some cases the location is really far away from a place and an error is returned.

I am unable to detect which comes with error in order to drop those rows. (the ones saying (None)

here is part of the data (thanks to ThePyGuy for instruction `df[:5].to_dict()` and Jonathan for suggestion):

```
{'calculado': {89943: '2021-05-14 23:12:00',
  118756: '2021-05-14 23:12:00',
  122327: '2021-05-14 23:12:00',
  131406: '2021-05-14 23:12:00',
  131408: '2021-05-14 23:12:00'},
 'geom': {89943: '14.25,-99.65',
  118756: '8.25,-98.35',
  122327: '7.549999999999997,-77.25',
  131406: '5.6499999999999995,-81.34999999999998',
  131408: '5.6499999999999995,-81.15'},
 'lat': {89943: 14.25,
  118756: 8.25,
  122327: 7.549999999999997,
  131406: 5.6499999999999995,
  131408: 5.6499999999999995},
 'lon': {89943: -99.65,
  118756: -98.35,
  122327: -77.25,
  131406: -81.34999999999998,
  131408: -81.15},
 'lugar': {89943: Location(None, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
  118756: Location(None, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
  122327: Location(Riosucio, Darién, Chocó, Pacífica, Colombia, (7.3423382, -77.19324367857044, 0.0)),
  131406: Location(None, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
  131408: Location(None, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0))},
 'valor': {89943: 192, 118756: 191, 122327: 188, 131406: 192, 131408: 192},
 'variable': {89943: 'T', 118756: 'T', 122327: 'T', 131406: 'T', 131408: 'T'}}
```

The type of column "lugar" is a `pandas.core.series.Series`

If I query the the first row it shows this...

```
>df['lugar'].iloc[0].raw
{'error': 'Unable to geocode'}
```

but cannot reference the column raw key to drop all error values
the object of a right result is:

```
>df['lugar'].iloc[2].raw

{'address': {'country': 'Colombia',
  'country_code': 'co',
  'county': 'Riosucio',
  'region': 'Pacífica',
  'state': 'Chocó',
  'state_district': 'Darién'},
 'boundingbox': ['6.7278677', '7.9561581', '-77.7486621', '-76.4829131'],
 'display_name': 'Riosucio, Darién, Chocó, Pacífica, Colombia',
 'lat': '7.3423382',
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
 'lon': '-77.19324367857044',
 'osm_id': 1343140,
 'osm_type': 'relation',
 'place_id': 258392009}
```

I will like to access these attributes and add another columns to the dataframe. like for example country code..

df.dtypes gives this

```
lon          float64
lat          float64
valor          int64
calculado     object
variable      object
geom          object
lugar         object
dtype: object
[32]
```

thanks, really new to PD and Python

Comment: please edit the post to provide the actual data, not an image.

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as text, we can not copy the contents from image. You can do `df[:5].to_dict()` and add the output data to the question.

Comment: Thanks JonathanLeon and @ThePyGuy for the suggestion I have replaced the image with the dict representation of the df.